# Java Mail Exception. Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;

Tags: java, email, ssl, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to **send an email** from my **java application**, and I am attempting to send the email by using SSL. I keep getting the **error**

> Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;

when I attempt to use the following code.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "false");
props.put("mail.smtps.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtps.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
```

But if I use the following code it works just fine:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
```

The variable `host` is an ip address, so I think it's strange that the error states that I *cannot connect to localhost on port 25*, when I am not connecting to localhost and the port is not `25`.

I need to be able to send the emails using `SMTPS` SSL, and not `SMTP`.
Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: how do you create your Transport instance ?

Comment: do you call Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");?

Comment: Hi yes, I am now using Transport transport =  session.getTransport("smtps") and the new error is that the application is unable to find the required certificate. I am reading on how to create a self-signed SMIME certificate

Comment: what did you use when you got the exception?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You always used Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps") even when you had your exception "Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;" or just now?

Comment: No, I started using it after reading your comment.

Comment: Have you tried setting the port as proposed below?

Comment: You'll want to fix all these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) as well.

Answer (score 2):

As all your properties are named `mail.smtps.*`, make sure to get your `Transport` instance as next:

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
```

While trying to debug, consider also switching to debug mode thanks to [`session.setDebug(true)`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Session.html#setDebug-boolean-)  in order to get more verbose log.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the port of smtp:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", String.valueOf(port));
```

Check properties info here:
[JavaMail summary](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html)